# Is there a way how to rename an IBM Watson intent?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Is there a way how to rename an IBM Watson intent?

In the UI, there is no such option.
[The API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2) docs do not have any means how to update intents either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about Watson Assistant. You should be able to rename the intent in the tool by [editing the intent](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-intents#intents-edit). Click the intent to open it for editing.

Comment: OMG, I was looking into an intent detail for days and didn't realize that I can simply click into the name and start writing.  Of course, the edit name is there!